# How to trigger "I am feeling lucky" button in google

Tags: button, google-search

I know that it sounds like really stupid question. But out of the interest:

1. Go to Google
2. Observe that there are two buttons (Search and I am Feeling lucky)
3. Start typing
4. You get immediate search results

So I realise I cannot use that button ... But why is it still on the GUI?

Thanks a lot for answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you have Javascript disabled.

Comment: ... unlike StackOverflow, I just discovered :)

Comment: Well, yes ... but. How many browsers do have javascript disabled? I am searching for normal, real world usage of the button...